# An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tooltip". java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception

My projects in *Eclipse Kepler* were working just fine until I downloaded *TestNG*.

After the *TestNG* download, I am unable to click on the run button for my code: after I click on run or even if I hover over on run the following error message is displayed.

```
An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tooltip". java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What does your source code look like?